# how to migrate multiple branches using git p4?

Tags: git, migration, bitbucket, perforce

We need to migrate multiple branches to git using git p4.

We are able to migrate but it creates only master branch on the bitbucket. But we need to migrate all the branches.
Git fusion is not available and it is outdated.

we are migrating from p4 to bitbucket. Expectation is to migrate multiple branches using git p4

Answer (score 0):

git-p4 can only infer branches if they are at the same level in the directory tree. e.g.

```
depot
|
 -main
|
 -v1.0
|
 -v1.2

git p4 sync --detect-branches "//depot@all"
```

If the branches are at a different level then you need to run git-p4 for each branch.

```
depot
|
 -main
|
branches
  |
   -v1.0
  |
   -v1.2

git p4 sync --branch=main "//depot/main@all"
git p4 sync --branch=v1.0 "//depot/branches/v1.0@all"
git p4 sync --branch=v1.2 "//depot/branches/v1.2@all"
```